# Where have the folders from public.me.com been moved to?

Tags: file-sharing, services, websites, webdav, icloud

Has the content that people made publicly accessible at http://public.me.com/ been moved somewhere, so that it can be accessed from the web?

Can the content still be accessed with WebDAV as [before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25015/4319)?

Answer (score 3):

Apple has [terminated](http://www.webcitation.org/626XlUEck) all Mobile Me services in Summer 2012, data stored on Mobile Me servers has been deleted in the meantime (or at least is not accessible any more).

There was an [initiative to archive public content](http://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=MobileMe), you may find what you are looking for there.